# Code Runner by Jun Han extension is bugging for me (?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

As I am new to coding, I am having problems with "Code Runner" extension in Visual Studio Code... Let me show you what I mean.

[image: Screenshot of the issue...]

The screenshot is showing the terminal and when I press the "Run Code" button located on the top right side of the window, sometimes instead of doing "***cd***" for **change directory**, the extension just does "***d***" ... its missing the "***c***" and after I pressed the "Run Code" again it works. I am wondering why that is. I went to the **settings.json** for said extension but was unable to find anything that's related to this problem.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Do you have any custom configuration settings? If so you can you post them into this question,

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues With hundreds of issues reported, I don't think you are the only one.

Comment: I don’t have any custom settings…

Comment: I’m learning C++ right now

Comment: What are your `"code-runner.executorMap"` settings for `cpp`?

Comment: ("cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",)